# Upgrading to Windows 7 breaks performance counters

Tags: windows, performancecounter

So, my workplace is finally getting around to replacing a Windows NT 4 system with Windows 7.  And I have to make sure that our old programs can run on the new system.

One that doesn't is a “performance check” service that keeps track of memory, CPU, disk, and network usage.  It relies heavily on performance counters.

My problem is that on the new Windows 7 box, some of the performance counters no longer work: I get a `PDH_INVALID_DATA` error when attempting to read the value.  The issue specifically affects the following counters:

```
\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec 
\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Time
\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Queue Length
\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Transfers/sec
\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
\Server\Bytes Total/sec
```

But other counters used in the same program do work (after some minor modification to deal with the “TCP” counters being split into “TCPv4” and “TCPv6”).

```
\Memory\Commit Limit
\Memory\Committed Bytes
\Process(_Total)\Thread Count
\TCPv4\Connections Established
\TCPv4\Segments/sec
```

The code involved (simplified by showing only one of the performance counters) is:

```
HQUERY               hQuery;
HCOUNTER             hCPUUsed;
DWORD                dwType;
PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE stCounter;

lStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery); // This same HQUERY object is used for all PDH calls
// ... error handling
lStatus = PdhAddCounter(hQuery, "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", 0, &hCPUUsed);
// ... error handling
lStatus = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(hCPUUsed, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, &dwType, &stCounter);
// ... error handling, logging a PDH_INVALID_DATA error from the above line
```

I tried running [`lodctr /r`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19374.windows-performance-monitor-unable-to-add-these-counters.aspx) to rebuild the performance counters, but this failed to resolve the issue.

Did something change under the hood between NT 4.0 and 6.1 that caused these performance counters to no longer work?  And how can I get them working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  Some of the counters require a call to [PdhCollectQueryData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372563(v=vs.85).aspx) before you can retrieve their data.  Windows NT 4.0 forgave the omission, but Windows 7 does not.